# How can I rsync only files from different subdirs that contain a particular string in the filename?

Tags: rsync

I have a tree of subdirs, some of which contain a file with the word "template" as part of the name. I want to rsync them to the same subdir tree in a different location.

eg:
Source:

```
curfolder/dir1/dir2/blah_template.ext
curfolder/dir3/dir4/foo_template.blah
```

Intended destination:

```
destfolder/dir1/dir2/blah_template.ext
destfolder/dir3/dir4/foo_template.blah
```

This command didn't work; it put all the files in the base destfolder, rather than in the correct subdirectories:

```
rsync -av curfolder/*/*/*template* destfolder
```

So I think I need a filter something like this, but this isn't working (it seems to just sync everything):

```
rsync -av -f"+ *template*" curfolder destfolder
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not accept my answer?

Comment: @NikoSP, thanks for your answer. It did work, however a link to some documentation explaining why it works would be the best possible answer, so if you can add that to your answer I'll accept it immediately.

Comment: i just added some explaination to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
rsync -av --include "*/" --include="*_template*" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs curfolder/ destfolder/
```

[rsync man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

what it does, expressed in words:

1. include every folder
2. include everything matching *_template*
3. exclude everything else
4. delete empty folders

The two includes are taking precedence over the exclude, so the exclude only matches everything the includes did not match.